# VHDL "casting" a constant into a signal?

Tags: vhdl

Is there a way to cast a constant value into a signal in order to send it into a function's parameter ?

Let's say I have this function:

```
Function mylogic(signal a, b, c : std_logic) return std_logic is
Begin
    return ((not a) and (not b) and c);
End Function;
```

And I would like to call it this way:

```
... mylogic('0',a(3),a(4))...
```

I cannot send '0' as a parameter because the function expects a signal, is there any way to have it work without declaring another signal to hold the value '0' ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just make the formal parameters constants (i.e. delete the word `signal` in the function declaration).

You're not driving them within the function anyway. (If you are, it isn't a function)

Then, when you call the function, the current value of each signal is passed as a constant to the function.

This won't work if your function uses the signal's attributes (such as `'event` or `'stable`, but `'length` etc which aren't specific to signals would be OK). If you DO need signal-specific attributes you'll need to add a signal anyway.